# RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (0) must match the existing size (5) at non-singleton dimension 0

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

In the following function:

```
   def dump_embedding(self, weight):
        with torch.no_grad():
            embeddings = self.forward(self.input_ids+self.id_offset)
        weight[self.id_offset:self.id_offset+self.length,:]=embeddings.detach()
```

I recive the following error:

```
weight[self.id_offset:self.id_offset+self.length,:]=embeddings.detach()
RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (0) must match the existing size (5) at non-singleton dimension 0.  Target sizes: [0, 768].  Tensor sizes: [5, 768]
```

Based on [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-the-expanded-size-of-the-tensor-must-match-the-existing-size/105523) seems that I should have other methods to expand the size of tensor, but I just don't know how.

Also the calling function is like this that may need change:

```
if self.decoder_prompt_encoder:
            if (self.decoder_original_embedding.num_embeddings <
                self.decoder_prompt_encoder.id_offset +
                self.decoder_prompt_encoder.length):
                self.underlying_model.resize_token_embeddings(
                    self.decoder_prompt_encoder.id_offset+
                    self.decoder_prompt_encoder.length
                )
            self.decoder_prompt_encoder.dump_embedding(
                self.decoder_original_embedding.weight)
```

Comment: If you don't provide an [MCVE] there we can't reproduce your result. But other than that, if one of your tensor has size zero in *any* dimension you should really reconsider what you're doing, as this means you have an empty tensor.

Comment: @flawr Thanks, yeah this error is raised just with one Transformer Model, but not with some others.